# Unity3d c# finding the biggest value of x in a Vector3 (xyz) List

Tags: c#, arraylist, unity-game-engine

How could i retrieve the biggest value of x in a Vector3 (that contain xyz) list?
Thank you!

Comment: Are you using List<Vector3> to store your vectors?

Comment: yes, I use List<Vector3>

Answer (score 3):

You can find the vector with the largest x using LINQ:

```
float xMax = vectors.Max(v => v.x);
Vector3 result = vectors.First(v => v.x == xMax);
```

This requires:

```
using System.Linq;
```

---

Alternatively, since the method above iterates over the source collection twice, you could add your own `IEnumerable<T>` extension to suit your needs.

There's a library called MoreLinq which already has something I have in mind: [MaxBy extension](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs).

That would make the solution a simple one liner (with a single iteration over source):

```
Vector3 result = vectors.MaxBy(v => v.x);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
var vectors = new List<Vector3>();
/* add data to list */

// Select biggest X.
var maxX = vectors.Max(v => v.x);
```

The LINQ statement `Max(v => v.x)` evaluates all the X'es in the Vector3 list and returns the biggest value it finds.

Comment: I actually misread OP's question and thought he was trying to find *the vector* with the biggest x and not the x value itself. Anyway, `vectors.Max(v => v.x)` will behave the same as `vectors.Select(v => v.x).Max()`.

Comment: Nice, thank you for sharing this information JensB and Discosultan !